# Интеграция 1С с Android

Tags: java, android, битрикс, 1с, интеграция

Есть ли какие-нибудь способы интеграции с 1С, не прибегая к решению "1с мобильное приложение"?
REST сразу можно откинуть, т. к. версия платформы не позволяет.

Comment: Почитай по данной теме: https://habrahabr.ru/post/176371/

Comment: И это почитай: [Способы интеграции с 1С](https://habrahabr.ru/company/1c/blog/308420/)

Comment: Пиши на **android studio** есть компоненты для 1С Что конкретно ты хочешь?
Что интегрировать?